# Katalon execution via Jenkins gets stuck

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I'm trying to execute my suite via Jenkins. I've created an account and a project as it's mentioned in Katalon's tutorial. When I run the project it gets stuck and doesn't complete the execution. This is the screen that I keep seeing:

[Console Output img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H56f7.png)

This is the build configuration:

[Build Configuration img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTXai.png)

I tried executing via cmd and it worked properly so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Thanks.

Comment: [SOLVED]
Just forgot to delete the -noExit -consoleLog parameters

Comment: Please use comment above as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved] 
I Just forgot to delete the -noExit and -consoleLog parameters